# How to write expectation of a multivariate random variable?

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus

My output is expectation, let's label it $$\boldsymbol{\mu} = \begin{bmatrix}\mu_{1} \\ \mu_{2}\end{bmatrix}$$.
The inputs are  $$\boldsymbol{x} = \begin{bmatrix}x_{1} \\ x_{2}\end{bmatrix}$$ and the joint robability density function $p(\boldsymbol{x})$.

How can I write a function that maps $\boldsymbol{x}$ and $p(\boldsymbol{x})$ to $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ (in multivariable calculus notation)? I am thinking along the lines of $$\boldsymbol{\mu} = \int \boldsymbol{x} \, p(\boldsymbol{x})$$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct. More accurately

$$\boldsymbol{\mu_1} = \int \boldsymbol{x_1} \, p(\boldsymbol{x})dx$$

where the integral is a two-integral on the space of $x$. The same is for $\boldsymbol{\mu_2}$

$$\boldsymbol{\mu_2} = \int \boldsymbol{x_2} \, p(\boldsymbol{x})dx$$

Comment: But can I write it in a more "linear algebra style" way, instead of writing out two functions (almost like the $\nabla$ operator, but for integration)?

Comment: @A.L.Verminburger, your formula is correct. I just wrote the meaning of the formula, in more detail, in terms of basic integrals.

Comment: I am still a little confused, because in your detailed notation, you are still using $\int \, dx$ rather than $\int \, dx_{1}$ and $\int \, dx_{2}$. Could you please expand it all the way to the level of $dx_{1}$ and $dx_{2}$?

Comment: @A.L.Verminburger, because, in general, it should be this way. $p(x)$ is the joint distribution of random variables $x_1$ and $x_2$ and you should take the integral on the whole space $x$. If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are independent and $p_1(x_1)$ and $p_2(x_2)$ are their distributions, then you can write $\int \, p_1(x_1)dx_1$

Comment: Is $\int x_{1} \, p(\boldsymbol{x}) d \, \boldsymbol{x} = \int \, \int \, x_{1} \, p(\boldsymbol{x}) \, dx_{1} \, dx_{2}$?

Comment: @A.L.Verminburger, yes. That is right.

Comment: OK, so for completion sake the brief and expanded notation should be: $$\boldsymbol{\mu} = \int \, \boldsymbol{x} \, p(\boldsymbol{x}) \, d\boldsymbol{x} = \begin{bmatrix} \int \int \, x_{1} p(x_{1},x_{2}) \, dx_{1} \, dx_{2} \\ \int \int \, x_{2} p(x_{1},x_{2}) \, dx_{1} \, dx_{2} \end{bmatrix}$$?

Comment: @A.L.Verminburger, Good on you :)